# .NET Google API access token failing with no refresh token specified

Tags: vb.net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to set up a class that can wrap around the .NET Google API so that I can use an Access Token that I have previously obtained to access a user's Google Drive. As of right now, I am just trying to get it to work so that I do not require a Refresh Token (more on that in a second). The ultimate goal is for somebody to go through a web page I have set up to authenticate where I obtain both an Access Token and a Refresh Token by directly calling to the Google Rest API (which I store in a database). They can then request to upload/download files onto their Drive on a different page which will first obtain the appropriate information from the database and then use the .NET Google API Library when accessing Drive.

However, when I attempt to access their Drive I get the the following error:

*The access token has expired and could not be refreshed. Errors: refresh error, refresh error, refresh error*

I know that the Access Token is valid because I obtain it only seconds earlier during my testing. Here is my code for setting up the Drive Service:

```
  ' NOTE: Code altered for brevity
  Public Sub Initialize(accessToken As String)
        ' Set up the client secret information based on the default constants
        Dim clientSecrets As New ClientSecrets()
        clientSecrets.ClientId = DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID
        clientSecrets.ClientSecret = DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET

        ' Set up a token based on the token data we got
        ' NOTE: Is it OK to leave some strings as NULL?
        Dim token As New Responses.TokenResponse()
        token.AccessToken = accessToken
        token.RefreshToken = ""
        token.TokenType = "Bearer"
        token.IssuedUtc = DateTime.Now
        token.ExpiresInSeconds = 3600
        token.Scope = "drive"
        token.IdToken = ""

        ' Set up a flow for the user credential
        Dim init As New GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer()
        init.ClientSecrets = clientSecrets
        init.Scopes = New String() {DriveService.Scope.Drive}
        init.Clock = Google.Apis.Util.SystemClock.Default

        ' Set up everything else and initialize the service
        Dim baseInit As New BaseClientService.Initializer()
        baseInit.HttpClientInitializer = New UserCredential(New GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(init), "user", token)
        baseInit.ApplicationName = APP_NAME

        _service = New DriveService(baseInit)
  End Sub
```

Shortly after that, I then use the following code to request a folder so I can check to see if it exists or not.

```
  Private Function GetDriveFolder(folderPath As String, ByRef folderIds As String(), Optional createMissingFolders As Boolean = False, Optional parentFolderId As String = "root") As Data.File
    Dim creatingFolderPath As Boolean = False
    Dim currentFolder As Data.File = Nothing
    Dim folderPathSplit As String() = folderPath.Replace("/", "\").Trim("\").Split("\")
    Dim folderIdList As New List(Of String)
    folderIds = {}

    ' Loop through each folder in the path and seek each out until we reach the end
    For x As Integer = 0 To folderPathSplit.Length - 1
        Dim result As FileList = Nothing

        If Not creatingFolderPath Then
            ' Build a list request which we will use to seek out the next folder
            Dim request As FilesResource.ListRequest = _service.Files.List()
            request.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='" & folderPathSplit(x) & "'"
            If currentFolder Is Nothing Then
                request.Q &= " and '" & EscapeDriveValue(parentFolderId) & "' in parents"
            Else
                request.Q &= " and '" & EscapeDriveValue(currentFolder.Id) & "' in parents"
            End If
            request.Spaces = "drive"
            request.Fields = "files(id, name)"

            ' Execute the search, we should only get a single item back
            ' NOTE: Error thrown on this request
            result = request.Execute()
        End If
        ' So on.....
```

So, I'm just trying to get it to work with only the Access Token for the time being because if it ends up getting refreshed I'll need to know so that I can update my database. However, if I do include the Refresh Token I get the following error:

*Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Unauthorized", Uri:""*

I'm guessing this has something to do with the way I have configured my application through the Dev Console but if I authenticate through the Google API Library by having it launch a browser to get my credentials everything works fine. So, I'm really not sure where to go from here as I haven't found anybody having similar problems and the guides don't cover specifying your own Access Token.

Also, as a quick note this is the URL I am using when having the user authenticate:

```
String.Format("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id={0}&state={1}&redirect_uri={2}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&access_type=offline&include_granted_scopes=true&prompt=select_account%20consent&response_type=code", GOOGLEAPI_CLIENTID, validateState, redirectUri)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an access-token then the simplest way to create a google credential is to use the [GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken()](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/0654fcd6493195156ca859f9e1f3aa07085feb5f/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/GoogleCredential.cs#L137) method passing in your access token.

This returns you a `GoogleCredential` instance which you can use to set the `HttpClientInitializer` property when building the `DriveService`.

If you then still get an error when accessing the drive service, then it's likely there's something incorrect in how you are asking for the access-token.

Comment: Awesome! Yeah I didn't know that even existed and it worked for me! Is there anything similar that also allows you to provide a Refresh Token as well?

Comment: This isn't as simple as it perhaps should be. See the answer here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1300#issuecomment-429746081